# popup window when user click anywhere on the page [jQuery & Html]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to know how can i popup a window to a particular website when user clicks anywhere on the page.just like popup companies.Am i able to do that in html using javascript & jQuery ?
i would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the click to the body and enter the url

```
$('body').click(function(){
  window.open('www.google.co.uk', 'New Window', 'height=200,width=200');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I Need it to be opened in a new browser window.not tab :(

Comment: I added 'specs' to it and it should work for you now

Comment: Thanks bro...its working.i am gonna set it to 1000X750.

Comment: BTW Am i able to make the current window active & popup window in back ?

Answer (score 1):

Complete sample on pure JavaScript:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var popup = function() {

        window.open ("http://example.com", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1");
    }

</script>
<body onclick="popup()">
    <h1>Click anywhere!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

You can specify some parameters of your popup window:

Width and Height:

```
window.open ("http://example.com", "Window","status=1,toolbar=1,width=500,height=300,resizable=yes");
```

Complete reference on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: How would you handle without "<body onclick="popup()">"

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('body').click(function(){window.open('www.stackoverflow.com')});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this-

```
<script>
     window.onclick = myFunction;
     function myFunction() {
       window.open('www.google.com', 'Popup Window', 'height=500,width=500');
     }
</script>
```